# Prevent Edge and Chrome from changing colors on autoform

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors, background-color

I created an embedded payment solution on my webpage. Once I made a payment, and entered my name, address and so forth, Edge and Chrome (and probably others too) suggest to save my information for me. No problem with that.
When I make a new payment, the browsers suggest some saved form data. Also fine with me. But when I click on the saved information, the color of my elements (name, address) which has been filled out for me, change. Before using the form data the background is transparent, while the text is #D8D8D8, after using form data, the background color becomes #E5F1FB, and the text color almost black.
I would like the background become transparent (or stay transparent)

How can I prevent browsers from changing colors on use of saved form data? Don't know if this is possible, and if possible, if this should be done by Javascript (jQuery) or CSS or something else.

So far I tried with CSS:

```
.subscription_payment:-webkit-autofill,  
.subscription_payment:-webkit-autofill:hover,  
.subscription_payment:-webkit-autofill:focus,  
.subscription_payment:-webkit-autofill:active  
 {  
 -webkit-transition: "color 9999s ease-out, background-color 9999s ease-out";  
 -webkit-transition-delay: 9999s;  
 transition: color 9999s ease-in-out, background-color 9999s ease-in-out;  
 transition-delay: 9999s;  
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px red inset !important;  
 -webkit-text-fill-color: blue !important;  
 -webkit-background-fill-color: yellow !important;  
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset !important;  
}
```

I tried in Edge and Chrome. The TEXT COLOR changes in Chrome, not in Edge. The background color does not change

Albert

Comment: try using auto complete off on input fields
autocomplete="off" in the input fields

Comment: Thanks. Tried that, doesn't help.

Comment: try in html form also

Comment: @Kairos is this 'autofill' you're talking about?

Comment: I guess, Coops. Haha. I tried to find out what it is called in English, but Google keeps returning Danish websites. LOL.
Pawan Kumar, I also tried in HTML form, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

If it's autofill you're talking about, I usually use this little snip of CSS to disable to background colour coming in.

```
.subscription_payment:-webkit-autofill,  
.subscription_payment:-webkit-autofill:hover,  
.subscription_payment:-webkit-autofill:focus,  
.subscription_payment:-webkit-autofill:active  
 {
   -webkit-transition: "color 9999s ease-out, background-color 9999s ease-out";
   -webkit-transition-delay: 9999s;
   transition: color 9999s ease-out, background-color 9999s ease-out;
   transition-delay: 9999s;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Kairos Hmm, strange. I'm not sure what is it then. Could you share a screenshot or a link?

Comment: Image: https://kairosplanner.com/img/kairosplanner-autofill-problem.png (tested in Chrome, not in Edge).
Current code:
 {
  -webkit-transition: "color 9999s ease-out, background-color 9999s ease-out";
  -webkit-transition-delay: 9999s;
  transition: color 9999s ease-in-out, background-color 9999s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 9999s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px red inset !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: blue !important;
  -webkit-background-fill-color: yellow !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset !important; }
Text changes, bg does not.

Comment: @Kairos So, you want to prevent the background from going light - you need to keep it transparent? Can you please amend your question with the CSS included?

Comment: @Kairos Ok, I think i understand what you mean. So you should remove your code and just use the one I have given you above. I've updated my answer to include your selectors. :-) This will keep your original styling for you.

Comment: I tried that, Coops, but it didn't work. With and without changing "input" to .subscription_payment, and with and without the lines I added/changed.

Comment: I think it can be done neither by CSS nor Javascript/jQuery. Made a onchange-listener to one of the elements that changes color. and put a color change into that listener, along with an alert that displays the color of the element. It returnes the color that it should be, but the color is incorrect. So the browser overrules the css/JavaScript. I need to find a way to disable autofill, since this color change totally demolishes the layout.

Comment: The solution I've given you works on all my websites. Are your textboxes inputs?

Comment: Yes, they are, Coops. I'd like to invite you to Watch along with TeamViewer. The code is a bit complex, so I can't copy a part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was so simple, that I never thought about it:
Do not use form-tags :)

AutoFORM only acts on the form HTML tag, but to send information to the backend, you don't need a form. As soon as I removed the inputs that asks for "name", "Company", "address 1", "address 2", "zip code", "city", "county" and "country" from the HTML-form, so that only the credit card information was in the form, the problem was gone :)

Albert

Comment: It's actually very straight-forward: <input type="text" value="" id="pay_name" class="subscription_payment" placeholder="Name"> for the first element. <input type="text" value="" id="pay_address" class="subscription_payment" placeholder="Address"> for the next element - just avoid the "<form>" tags. Then the browser will not use autofill (and change the colors).